# Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found PHP 7.x

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

My current PHP version is 7.1. I have recently followed some link. All are saying same things.

See: `zahid dot smz at gmail dot com` notes : 
 http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php

Download latest file from here : http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

My Code:

```
<?php
class workerThread extends Thread {
  public function __construct($i){
    $this->i=$i;
  }

  public function run(){
      while(true){
        echo $this->i;
        sleep(1);
      }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
  $workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
  $workers[$i]->start();
}
exit;
?>
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\thread\test.php on line 2
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your server afterwards?

Comment: @mega6382 Yes I have restarted my xampp server